# Record Already Locked by this Session in Delphi over the network with long table names

Tags: delphi, session, paradox

I have found a problem in Paradox when using table names that are longer than 8 characters.  If you have 2 table with names that are longer than 8 characters and the first 8 characters match, locking a record on one will be seen internally to paradox as a lock on both.  So, I have a table named Minister and another named MinisterMP.  They both have a number of records.  If I go into edit mode on record 3 of Minister and then try to go into edit mode on record 3 on MinisterMP, I get a 'Record already locked by this session' error.

This only happens if the table is over a network.  If it's on the local machine, there is no problem.  My guess is that Paradox is getting the Short filename and using only the first 8 character.  On the local machine is getting the dos 8 character name and on the network is the entire name.  It may be a setting in the network.  I found a reference to  NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation, when looking for short names.  Microsoft suggest turning this on to increase performance.

So, if you get the Record already Locked message, check the table name.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: This is a *Question and Answer* site, which means that before an *answer* can be posted, there must first be a *question*. If you'd like to share your information, that's fine, but you have to do it properly by first posting a question that explains the problem and asks a question about how to solve it. You can then post your *solution* as an actual answer to that question, just as you see in every other post here. Posting self-answers is acceptable; posting non-questions isn't. :-)

Answer (score -1):

..and he is close but 2012 server has that disabled by default. You need to enable for paradox to work right if the files are hosted there. not sure about 2008 R2.

Comment: what are you referring to? (who is close, with what, to what?)